# "Who we are?"or "who are we?"

Tags: meaning, descriptive-grammar

"Who we are?" or, "who are we?" Which one of these expressions is the the correct way to title a content equivalent to about-us meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Either is possible.  Note, though, that '*Who we are*' is not a question.